# using if conditions to summon appropriate stages in aggreagations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This below is an imaginary syntax i wish it was availabe so i could fetch my sessions with .
i have a Course collection that every single course has a sessions array as sub-document 
i want to fetch courses based on my users query params when they search, so that if somebody asked for sessions from a specific teacher i use that in my $match stage in aggregate if not just find all sessions from all teacher , the same applies for subject and status if they get defined use them if not ignore them and find all possible.

there is another procedure if there was a keyword in mongo or aggregate that i could use and by that it knew that it find all something like * or regex syntax

i also come across to a $cond keyword but did not match my expectations in here .

```
app.get('/sessions',(req, res)=>{
    const teacher = req.query.teacherId
    const subject = req.query.subjectId
    const status = req.query.statusId

    Course.aggregate([
       if(teacher) {$match:{teacher:teacher}},
       if(subject) {$match:{subject:subject}},
       if(status)  {$match:{status:status}}
    ]).then(sessions=>res.json(sessions))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))

})
```

not sure if this helps but this is my Course Schema

```
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    status:{type:String,required:true},
    subject:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref :'subjects'
    },
    teacher:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref :'users'
    },
    sessions:[
        {
         Date:{type:Date,required:true},
         timeStart:{type:String,required:true},
         timeEnd  :{type:String,required:true},
         students :[{
             type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref :'users'
         }]   
        }
    ]
})
```

Thank You in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
app.get('/sessions', (req, res) => {
  const teacher = req.query.teacherId
  const subject = req.query.subjectId
  const status = req.query.statusId

  const query = [];
  if (teacher) query.push({ $match: { teacher: teacher } });
  if (subject) query.push({ $match: { subject: subject } });
  if (status) query.push({ $match: { status: status } });
  Course.aggregate(query).then(sessions => res.json(sessions))
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
})
```

**REMEMBER,** I did not check if the query is okay.

Comment: Thanks so much.. yeah works ...  making a query and then passing it to find(query) but idk why i cant do the same with aggregate ... even when i try apply an aggregate method on my Course model empy(Course.aggregate([ ]).then...) it doesnt return anything back. no error just nothing get back... for (Course.find({}).then..) i get everything just doesnt make sense